# How to put multiple parameters into onClick attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how to put multiple parameters into onClick so you can run one parameter first and the other parameter next.

```html
<p id='demo'> </p>
<a onClick="myWindow.resizeBy(250, 250); document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Paragraph changed!';">
Click this for a change
</a>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` of what?

Comment: You can't nest `"` inside `"` without escaping them.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry I had not put the correct code in. I fixed it just now

Comment: You can put as many statements as you like into the onclick attribute. Provided `myWindow` exists your code should work. What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: They're not "parameters", they are instructions. Embedded code, if you want.

Comment: the problem is that the message in my paragraph is not comming up

Comment: @VictorMalhotra That's probably because the `myWindow` variable does not exist so the `innerHTML`-part is not even executed. You should open the development console of your browser and check for any javascript errors.

Comment: You do it just like you have. If it isn't working, then it is likely because (as  subarachnid said)  `myWindow` doesn't exist (it certainly doesn't in the code you provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad and unclear. Can you provide a code example or a diagram?

Maybe, if you only want to call two seperate functions in sequence:

`... onClick="runActions()" ...`

```js
function runActions() {
  // first function you want to call
  console.log("Hello, World!");
  // second
  alert("Bye!");
}
```

EDIT:

try this:

```html
<a onClick="changeWindow()">
Click this for a change
</a>
```

```js
function changeWindow() {
  myWindow.resizeBy(250, 250);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Paragraph changed!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me more but I also want to ask can you only call one thing in the Onclick attribute

Comment: As far as I know, yes, you can only call one method from the attribute, that's the cleanest way to handle it.

Comment: Also, please accept my answer by clicking the green tick if this helped you finding a solution, thanks!

Comment: @PhilippMolitor — You're completely wrong. The value of an `onclick` attribute is the same as the body of a function. You can have as many statements there as you like.

Comment: Also, `onClick="changeWindow"` doesn't do anything!

Answer (score 0):

`$('#element').on("click",function (){alert("hello");document.location="/path you want to redirect" });`You can use jQuery .
Like you can add more functionality ..